# Please tell me what kind of grass this is

Tags: identification, grass, plant-care, planting

[image]

This grass grows naturally in Yanbu, Saudi Arabia

Answer (score 2):

hmm.  taking a wild guess here...I see sand.  They could be sea oats.

Comment: Sea oat is _Uniola paniculata_ and it is an American specie.